# Filter predicate for equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, filter, java-8, predicate

I am trying to write a filter predicate for `Objects.nonNull` and `equalsIgnoreCase`, but I am not able to create a predicate for the `equalsIgnoreCase` part. Can I have some suggestions?

My code is :

```
basicDetailEntity.forEach(prj -> {
    CharlieAddress billToAddress = addressList.stream()
        .filter(add -> Objects.nonNull(add.getSiteDuns())
                       && add.getSiteDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getBillToDuns())
                       && Objects.nonNull(add.getOrgName())
                       && add.getOrgName().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getOperatingUnit()))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

I have created the two predicates for the nonNull part, but I'm finding it difficult to create them for the `equalsIgnoreCase` one, any suggestion will help.

```
public static final Predicate<CharlieAddress> CHARLIE_ADDRESS_DUNS_PRESENT =
        add -> Objects.nonNull(add.getSiteDuns());

public static final Predicate<CharlieAddress> CHARLIE_ADDRESS_ORG_PRESENT =
        add -> Objects.nonNull(add.getOrgName());
```

Comment: sure..Thnx for the suggestion..appreciate it.

Comment: what is the structure of all those classes? we supposed to guess?

Comment: There is no improvement in using `Objects.nonNull(…)` instead of the simple `… != null`. Besides that, your code lacks a useful purpose. The first code fragment does not even compile, but even when you add the missing brackets, it’ll be a value producing expression within a `forEach` that will just drop every value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your condition relies upon two arguments. You need the **address** and you need the **prj** (project? -- the rest of this answer assumes so).

```
add.getSiteDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getBillToDuns())
 ^                                  ^
```

A predicate takes a *single* argument and returns a boolean, so unless you have a lambda that acts as a closure which captures some variable from the enclosing scope (which if you want the predicate to be a static field, you probably **do not**) then what you're asking for is not possible

```
final Project prj = /*something*/; // must be final or "effectively final"
Predicate<CharlieAddress> foo =
    add -> add.getSiteDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getBillToDuns());
                                            // ^ captured
```

There is another interface, [BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) which takes 2 arguments. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

```
BiPredicate<CharlieAddress, Project> foo =
    (add, prj) -> add.getSiteDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getBillToDuns());
```

---

You didn't ask but your existing predicates can be simplified with `!= null`

```
public static final Predicate<CharlieAddress> CHARLIE_ADDRESS_DUNS_PRESENT =
    add -> add.getSiteDuns() != null;

public static final Predicate<CharlieAddress> CHARLIE_ADDRESS_ORG_PRESENT =
    add -> add.getOrgName() != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I can assume that the objects in the `addressList` will never have null value for `prj.getBillToDuns()` and `prj.getBillToDuns()` your code can be simplified from

```
basicDetailentity.forEach(prj -> {
  CharlieAddress billToAddress = addressList.stream()
      .filter(add -> Objects.nonNull(add.getSiteDuns())
          && add.getSiteDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getBillToDuns())
          && Objects.nonNull(add.getOrgName())
          && add.getOrgName().equalsIgnoreCase(prj.getOperatingUnit()))
      .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

To

```
basicDetailentity.forEach(prj -> {
  CharlieAddress billToAddress = addressList.stream()
      .filter(add -> prj.getBillToDuns().equalsIgnoreCase(add.getSiteDuns())
          && prj.getOperatingUnit().equalsIgnoreCase(add.getOrgName()))
      .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Or if you are allowed to use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from [Apache Common Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) then it can be simply

```
basicDetailentity.forEach(prj -> { 
  CharlieAddress billToAddress = addressList.stream()
  .filter(add -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(add.getSiteDuns(), prj.getBillToDuns())
      && StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(add.getOrgName(), prj.getOperatingUnit()))
  .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

If you still just want to do it yourself, create a utility method which takes two strings as parameters and returns true, if they are both not null and are equal ignoring cases. And then use it as a predicate in your filter

```
private boolean myEqualsIgnoreCase(String oneStr, String twoStr) {
    return oneStr != null && twoStr != null && oneStr.equalsIgnoreCase(twoStr);
}

basicDetailentity.forEach(prj -> { 
  CharlieAddress billToAddress = addressList.stream()
  .filter(add -> myEqualsIgnoreCase(add.getSiteDuns(), prj.getBillToDuns())
      && myEqualsIgnoreCase(add.getOrgName(), prj.getOperatingUnit()))
  .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

### Note

Apart from above explanations, I believe this code will not be very efficient for large collections, If I were you, I would implement some kind of searching logic based on Key-Value for addressList, so that I can supply a key containing `SiteDunes` and `OrgName` and then map (Key-Value) would returning corresponding address object as the value.

Comment: So this answer has been edited just to remove below the text 
"I hope it help, if it does, please upvote", with a comment saying "trim chat", really?